# FOSUserBundle after bad credentials redirects to wrong route

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have clean Symfony 2.8.4 app only with installed FOSUserBundle. I configured it with basic documentation. I changed routes, because I need them translated.

I changed those routes:

**/login => /prihlaseni**

and

**/logout => /odhlasit**

At the route /prihlaseni I can see the form, but when I send bad credentials I get **No route found for "GET /login" (from  http://localhost/project/web/app_dev.php/prihlaseni")**

I can't find any reason, why is it redirect again to /login. Why it could be so?

My routing.yml:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profil

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /registrace

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /reset

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profil

fos_user_security_login:
    path:      /prihlaseni
    defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login, _method: POST }

fos_user_security_logout:
    path:      /odhlasit
    defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout, _method: POST }
```

My security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

        anonymous:    true

        logout:
            path:   /odhlasit
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/prihlaseni$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/registrace, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/reset, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Registration, login with correct credentials and logout works fine.

Comment: can we see your security.yml file?

Comment: Yes, it's in updated question.

Comment: Did you clean cache?

Comment: maybe it's just part of the problem, but add `login_path: /prihlaseni` to `form_login`.

Comment: @AnnaAdamchuk cache was cleared

Comment: @Federico I thought, I tried this, but it's working. Thanks. :)